# Why am I not being able to read the Excel sheet in my Jupyter Notebook

Tags: excel, pandas

I have the excel sheet named data in the same folder where I have the jupyter notebook. But it is still showing file not found error as you can see in the image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rreFA.png

Comment: try to add directly the code in your question, and copy paste also the error text

in this way we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that it is indeed in your jupyter folder

To do so, write this snipped of code in a new cell and check the result

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```